# Cucumber Scenario description is not getting imported into Xray

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-xray

Our Cucumber Feature files are designed to have Scenario Description with Title.

[image]

So when I import feature files into Xray via Jenkins, Feature description gets copied over into Xray Test description area rather I want Cucumber Scenario description to be copied. Is that possible?

I am running Jira DC v8.9.0 with Xray v3.6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process of importing the cucumber .feature files is detailed [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Importing+Cucumber+Tests+-+REST); it does not include all the details though.
Right now, the import process is non-configurable.
Therefore, unfortunately the behaviour you're looking for is not possible.
The import process has evolved throughout the years though, based on customer feedback. My recommendation would be to ask the team for an improvement related to this, by reaching out the [support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2).
Please note that the Gherkin steps (your "Scenario description") will be on the specific field for hosting the gherkin specification.
The scenario title will be on the Test issue' summary.

Comment: Yeah Scenario Title is getting mapped to Test Issue Summary. Thanks @Sergio for checking and I have asked Xray support. Reference: SUPPORT-49752

Comment: Great, can I kindly ask to mark my answer as correct? Thanks

Comment: This Turned out to be a bug in Xray and the team is investigating it. https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAY-8468